# Mean stack deployment on Bluemix: "MongoError: no primary found in replicaset"

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, ibm-cloud, mean-stack

I'm struggling with this problem for a day now. I couldn't find anything on Google/SO, so I hope any of you can help me out.

I have a MEAN stack application that I want to deploy to a Bluemix instance.

On Bluemix I created:

- 1 Node.js app cf instance
- 1 Compose for MongoDB instance

I did bind the mongodb instance to the app.

When i deploy from my pc with cf push "myapp", everything works well up to the point where the app is started. I get the following error:

> 2016-12-03T01:20:24.30+0100 [App/0]      OUT { [MongoError: no primary found in replicaset]
>   2016-12-03T01:20:24.30+0100 [App/0]      OUT   name: 'MongoError',
>   2016-12-03T01:20:24.30+0100 [App/0]      OUT   message: 'no primary found in replicaset' }
>   2016-12-03T01:20:24.35+0100 [App/0]      ERR error: Forever detected script exited with code: 0
>   2016-12-03T01:20:24.36+0100 [App/0]      ERR error: Script restart attempt #3
>   2016-12-03T01:20:26.25+0100 [App/0]      ERR Could not connect to MongoDB!
>   2016-12-03T01:20:26.25+0100 [App/0]      OUT url mongodb://xxx:xxx@sl-eu-lon-2-portal.3.dblayer.com:15736,sl-eu-lon-2-portal.2.dblayer.com:15736/admin?ssl=true

(I see this by running a cf log after the deployment)

The deployment output ends with this (I assume from seeing this, that the app itself is ok, just starting up doesn't work):

```
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 down
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
0 of 1 instances running, 1 starting
```

These are the relevant parts of my cloud-foundry.js that is being used. I checked already that the environment is set correctly:

```
'use strict';

var cfenv = require('cfenv'),
    appEnv = cfenv.getAppEnv();
var cfMongoUrl = (function() {
    if (appEnv.getService('mean-mongo')) {
        var mongoCreds = appEnv.getService('mean-mongo').credentials;
        return mongoCreds.uri || mongoCreds.url;
    } else {
        throw new Error('No service names "mean-mongo" bound to the application.');
    }
}());

...

module.exports = {
    port: appEnv.port,
    db: {
        uri: cfMongoUrl,
        options: {
            user: '',
            pass: ''
        }
    },
    ...
}
```

Does anyone have any idea how to fix this and why this is happening? Do I need to create a replica instance? And how does that work?

Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: How are you trying to connect to the db? Can you show us your code?

Comment: Also include the mongodb npm version that you're installing.  Quick search uncovers this [bug submission](https://jira.mongodb.org/browse/NODE-746) which seems to link to version 2.2.0.  In version 2.2.1, they seem to have relaxed the same domain requirement/best practice.